# Reference request: Deligne cohomology

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Can anyone suggest an introductory reference to Deligne cohomology, possibly with a discussion of applications in physics, e.g. the Kalb Ramond field being a 3-cocycle?

On top of that, are there any known examples of space in which Deligne cohomology doesn't involve computing hypercohomology? Similar to the affine case of deRham cohomology for algebraic varieties?